# Sending a function via tcp in python

Tags: python, tcp

Is it possible to send a funtion or even just code via TCP in python

(it is very possible this question is rediculous I have no idea what I'm doing)

Comment: what are you trying to achieve, by doing so?

Comment: I basically want to run a bit of code a user can send but in a class which is in a script on the server

Comment: Yes I understand that's what you're trying to do, but what by doing so, what are you trying to achieve? What's the root problem you're solving?

Comment: I believe you can achieve this by sending a binary representation of this "function" in client side, so in server side you can unpack this information and eval it. This can be dangerous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

Proof: look at the various online python editors, they do it.

For ideas how you can do it from within Python, look at the built-in functions at https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html, especially `eval` and `compile`.

In any case, you should consider the security implications of executing code entered by the user. If you're not able to create a secure sandbox in which such code can be executed you should not do it, at least not in a website that can be accessed by potentially untrusted users. And to be honest, you are not able to build such a sandbox if this is the first time you hear about `eval` and `compile`.

**TL;DR:** Don't do it.